# Adding multiple markers to a map

Tags: javascript, jquery, leaflet

I am trying to Lopo through PHP records and use the coordinates to populate markers on a leaflet map.

I however am getting an error in the console:

> Error: Invalid LatLng object: (18.473396, undefined)

**Php:**

```
           <?php foreach($positions as $position):
                    $longitude = get_field( 'longitude', 'category_' . $position->term_id . '' );
                    $latitude = get_field( 'latitude', 'category_' . $position->term_id . '' );
            ?>
               <div class="marker" data-lat="<?php echo $latitude; ?>" data-lng="<?php echo $longitude; ?>"></div>
           <?php endforeach; ?>
```

The html output for the above is:

```
<div class="marker" data-lat="33.985571" data-lng="18.470870"></div>
<div class="marker" data-lat="33.994995" data-lng="18.473396"></div>
```

**The JS**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var map = L.map('mapid').setView([51.505, -0.09], 13);

    L.tileLayer('https://api.mapbox.com/styles/v1/{id}/tiles/{z}/{x}/{y}?access_token={accessToken}', {
        attribution: 'Map data &copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors, <a href="https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.0/">CC-BY-SA</a>, Imagery © <a href="https://www.mapbox.com/">Mapbox</a>',
        maxZoom: 18,
        id: 'mapbox/streets-v11',
        tileSize: 512,
        zoomOffset: -1,
        accessToken: 'pk.eyJ1IjoibWFwYm94IiwiYSI6ImNpejY4NXVycTA2emYycXBndHRqcmZ3N3gifQ.rJcFIG214AriISLbB6B5aw'
    }).addTo(map);


var markers = [];
$.each($('.marker'), function () {
    var marker = [];
    var lat = $(this).attr('data-lat');
    var lng = $(this).attr('data-lng');
    marker = [lat, lng];
    markers.push( marker );
});

    for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
        marker = new L.marker([markers[i][1], markers[i][2]]).bindPopup(markers[i][0]).addTo(map);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An Array is starting with the index 0. So lat = 0, lng = 1:

```
for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
        marker = new L.marker([markers[i][0], markers[i][1]]).bindPopup(markers[i][0]).addTo(map);
}
```

It is also possible to use the array directly, because the array has only lat and lng:

```
for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
        marker = new L.marker(markers[i]).bindPopup(markers[i][0]).addTo(map);
}
```

**Pan to the markers**

Add your markers to a `L.FeatureGroup` then you can move / pan the map to the markers after creation:

```
var fg = L.featureGroup().addTo(map);
for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
        marker = new L.marker(markers[i]).bindPopup(markers[i][0]).addTo(fg);
}
map.fitBounds(fg.getBounds())
```

Comment: Thank you very much. The error goes away but now it doesn't show my markers, but always the original position of the map from here `var map = L.map('mapid').setView([51.505, -0.09], 13);`

Comment: How can I get it to initially display the markers I have set in the loop? I tried `var map = L.map('mapid').setView([lat, lng], 13);` but it says that lat and lng don't exist. Obviously because they are only set in the loop.

Comment: I updated the answer. Init the map as befor `var map = L.map('mapid').setView([51.505, -0.09], 13);` and then you get read out the bounds from all markers thogter to move the map.

Comment: Thanks again, you are really helping me so much. I know I am pushing it now, but I have one last issue and that is it doesn't show all the markers. I am trying to figure out how to set a zoom value or something like that on this because changing the initial zoom doesn't do anything.

Comment: When all markers you are creating added to the `FeatureGroup` it must show all markers. If you add some markers directly to the map, then it can't be detected with `getBounds()`. But you can change the Zoom after `map.fitBounds()` with `map.setZoom(7)`

Comment: Thank you, I will give that a go!